# jquery - Display only 15 list items in a UL

Tags: jquery, html

I have a list that is generated by WordPress and I there is no way to limit how many tags to display through the function it self.

With jQuery I decided to do this to display only the first 15:

```
$j(function(){
    if( $j('#popular-tags').length > 0 ){
        var displayAmt = 15;

        var list = $j(this).find('ul');
        for(var i=1; i <= displayAmt; i++ ){
            ....
        }
    }
});
```

I'm a bit lost on how to iterate through each list item. But i have a class called `.not-display` that I want to add to the respective list item. I also wasn't sure if I need to use the `.each()` function that jQuery provides.

Can someone enlighten me?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'll find that most of the time, a loop is not necessary with jQuery:

```
var displayAmt = 15;
$j('#popular-tags li').slice(displayAmt).hide();
```

This code finds all the `li` elements within the `#popular-tags` div, uses [`slice()`](http://api.jquery.com/slice/) to get every element after the 15th element, and calls `hide()` on them all. You can also choose to call `remove()` instead if you wish.

Comment: +1 never fast enough `:)`, was about to do the same thing. http://jsfiddle.net/markcoleman/4uVrn/

Comment: that was much simpler than the route i was going. Im used to low level java programing(which thrives on loops) so im still getting use to jquery ty :D

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest using the [`lt` selector](http://api.jquery.com/lt-selector/), which takes a zero-based index:

```
$("ul > li:lt(15)").show();
```

Answer (score 1):

Taking the opposite of Karims answer using the [gt selector](http://api.jquery.com/gt-selector/)

```
$("ul > li:gt(14)").hide();
```

or if you want to apply your class:

```
$("ul > li:gt(14)").addClass("not-display");
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try the [Show First N Items jQuery Plugin](https://github.com/solarmosaic/jquery-show-first). All you need to write is this:

```
<ul class="show-first" data-show-first-count="15"  data-show-first-has-control="false">
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
    <li>5</li>
    <li>6</li>
    <li>7</li>
    <li>8</li>
    <li>9</li>
    <li>10</li>
    <li>11</li>
    <li>12</li>
    <li>13</li>
    <li>14</li>
    <li>15</li>
    <li>16</li>
    <li>17</li>
    <li>18</li>
    <li>19</li>
    <li>20</li>
</ul>
```

It will automatically convert to this:

```
<ul class="show-first" data-show-first-count="15" data-show-first-has-control="false">
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
    <li>5</li>
    <li>6</li>
    <li>7</li>
    <li>8</li>
    <li>9</li>
    <li>10</li>
    <li>11</li>
    <li>12</li>
    <li>13</li>
    <li>14</li>
    <li>15</li>
    <li style="display: none;">16</li>
    <li style="display: none;">17</li>
    <li style="display: none;">18</li>
    <li style="display: none;">19</li>
    <li style="display: none;">20</li>
</ul>
```

Fyi, I contributed code to this plugin.